# Is it possible to render an output image in Shiny just by placing the text editor cursor inside a numericInput control?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app where I have to type in different dimensions (like length and height) of a machined part. I have an image of the part showing which numericInput box on the app is related to which dimension of the part, but it would be nicer if instead of having a single image with all the dimensions descriptions on it to have an image for each specific numericInput. That way when the user place the text editor cursor inside the numericInput box, only the relevant dimension will be showing on the picture. Any ideas?

tks

Comment: Without code or an image, it is difficult to understand your question to help you, how are you displaying the image in Shiny? I would think you could have 2 input variables(height and width) and it only will display on the image what the user has inputted into Shiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do it, but this works. We use `onclick()` along with `show()` and `hide()` to control some `hidden()` elements. All these functions are from the `shinyjs` package. Note that these are two different image files stored in the */www* directory for the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("one","First input"),
  textInput("two","Second input"),
  hidden(img(src = "one.png", id = "image1")),
  hidden(img(src = "two.png", id = "image2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  onclick("one", {
    show("image1")
    hide("image2")
  })

  onclick("two", {
    show("image2")
    hide("image1")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This app gives the following when clicking in "First input" and "Second input" respectively.

[image: First input selected shows black box with red line for width]
[image: Second input selected shows black box with red line for height]